# What is difference between Collections.synchronizedCollection and Collections.synchronizedList or Collections.synchronizedSet

Tags: java, collections

We can use the Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection c) for all objects of type Collection like Set and List right, why we have separate methods like - Collections.synchronizedList or Collections.synchronizedSet.

Comment: Do you want to work with a `Collection`, `List`, or `Set`? That's why you have all three.

Answer (score 1):

There are other interfaces that are `Collection` apart from `List` and `Set` e.g. [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). You could synchronize it using `Collections#synchronizedCollection`.

Anyway, if you happen to work with synchronized collections, give a look at the classes at [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. Some of them are [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) (for `List`) and [`CopyOnWriteArraySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html) (for `Set`).

Answer (score 1):

If you call `Collections.synchronizedCollection` on a `List`, then you can't use the `List` methods on the returned `Collection`.  In the other direction, you can't call `Collections.synchronizedList` on something that might be an arbitrary `Collection`, including a `Set`.

Comment: but still we can cast Collection to List or Set, then we can use those methods specific to List or Set right?

Comment: If you cast the collection returned by Collections.synchronizedCollection() to List or Set, you'll get a ClassCastException. The returned object is a wrapper around the original collection. It's not the original one. And, in the case of synchronizedCollection(), it only implements Collection, not List nor Set. Look at the source code to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it throws ClassCastException, i looked into the source code of the Collections class, the method Collections.synchronizedCollection(c) returns the wrapper synchronized methods only for Collection type, Where as the Collections.synchronizedList(list) method has the wrapper synchronized methods for all methods of the List, similarly for the Set also.

So have to use the specific synchronized methods in Collections for specific input type.

thanks for help.